# How to determine last element when using an iterator?

Tags: java, iterator

I love to use a for loop with the iterator principle, like

```
for(String s : collectionWithStrings)
    System.out.println(s + ", ");
```

Question: How can I determine if the current element is the last one?

With an own index like `int = 0; i < collection.size(); i++` this is possible with `i == collection.size() - 1`, but not nice. Is it also possible to determine the last element with an iterator for the example above?

Comment: No. If you want to check for the position, switch to the other syle.

Comment: The enhanced for-loop is rather specialized. Its job is to provide a very short, simple representation for some very simple, but frequently occurring, cases. If you have trouble getting what you want from it, don't use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed, the [`Iterator#hasNext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#hasNext%28%29) method returns a boolean determining if the iterator will return another element with the `next` method.

Your iteration can be put as this:

```
Iterator<String> iterator = collectionWithString.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    String current = iterator.next();
    // if you invoke iterator.hasNext() again you can know if there is a next element
}
```

Comment: Yes, but you are not given access to the iterator with the enhanced `for` loop shown above.

Comment: @DuncanJones Yes, but the OP also asked _Is it also possible to determine the last element with an iterator for the example above?_

Answer (score 5):

Just use the [`hasNext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#hasNext%28%29) method.

```
if(!iterator.hasNext()) {
    // this is the last element
}
```

Normally, we iterate using an `Iterator` as so:

```
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    Object obj = iterator.next();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible with an [enhanced for loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) without maintaining your own counter. To be honest, this is my one deciding factor when I choose which type of for loop to use.

When using an `Iterator`, one has access to the [`hasNext()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#hasNext%28%29) method which will return false when you are processing the last element.

Comment: Thank you. This was also my deciding factor for the loop type. As it stands, it will be my deciding factor for the future. :)